# В чем разница между операторами сравнения != и <> в Python?

Tags: python

Объясните, пожалуйста, разницу между операторами сравнения != и <>.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators

Answer (score 4):

Это оба оператора, **не равно**

Различие в том, что  , "**<>**" - такого оператора сравнения нет в питоне.

**Не равно** в питоне - это "**!=**"

Более подробно про операторы сравнения можно [тут посмотреть](https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2019/10/14/python-comparison-operators-ru/)

Comment: Уточнение: [такой оператор был в Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators), и наверное где-то в примерах в интернете его еще можно увидеть.